# What is max length for pod name in k8s?

Tags: kubernetes

In Kubernetes docs [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/#working-with-pods) I can see that the pod name follows a valid "DNS subdomain name" which means 253 char limit but here in this article [here](https://pauldally.medium.com/why-you-try-to-keep-your-deployment-names-to-47-characters-or-less-1f93a848d34c) they have mentioned that you should try to keep deployment name below 47 char as pod name limit to 63 char. Also, I tried creating a pod with a deployment name of more than 63 chars but the pod name got truncated to 63 chars.
So, what is the correct char limit for the pod name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A domain name is a series of labels with max length of 255; where each label with max length of 63 bytes. The K8s document is referring to the label. See [here](https://www.freesoft.org/CIE/RFC/1035/9.htm) for the RFC standard.